# SingleChildScrollView clips height of column in "drag_and_drop_lists" plugin

Tags: flutter

I'm using the ["drag_and_drop_lists" plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_lists) to move around `ListTile` items in a column in a Flutter app (latest version of Flutter) on Android. My problem: `ListTile` items with a long subtitle value get clipped in height. In the example below, there's text in a line below after "key from & drop off" that I can't see:

[image]

The widget on this screen is a `DragAndDropLists`. "1", "2", and "3" are the `DragAndDropList` in it.

Here's what the `ListTile` looks like - it has a height of 184 pixels:

[image]

The plugin wraps my `ListTile` in a number of widgets. The last one with a height of 184 pixels is the column:

[image]

That `Column` is in a `SingleChildScrollView`. And that's the first one with the wrong height — 145 pixels:

[image]

[Here's the line in the source code](https://github.com/philip-brink/DragAndDropLists/blob/master/lib/drag_and_drop_list.dart#L156) creating that `SingleChildScrollView`. If I remove the `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` attribute there, I can scroll my `ListTile`. Here, the title is now missing, but the whole subtitle is then visible:

[image]

I don't know how to get the `SingleChildScrollView` to show my `Column` at full height. I tried a number of things but nothing worked. I didn't file a GitHub issue with the plugin, as the plugin author hasn't responded to an issue for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix this with a regular `ListTile`. So instead, I now show a separate `Text` widget with the text. And that doesn't get clipped.